# Recurrence relation of the form R(x,y)=yR(x-1,y)+(x-(y-1))R(x,y-1)

Tags: co.combinatorics, generating-functions, recurrences

Consider the recurrence
$$
R(x,y)= yR(x-1,y)+ (x-(y-1))R(x,y-1) 
$$
where for any $R(p,c)$, $c$ does not exceed $p$, and $R(p,p)=R(p,1)=1$.

I´ve tried to write $R(x,y)$ as a sum of coefficients of $R(x,1),R(x-1,1),...,R(1,1)$, but do not get how to write the coefficient of $R(x-k,1)$ in a way that does not implies a sum of products.

How can a coefficient of $R(x-k,1)$ be written?
Does not matters if it´s in closed form or not.

Comment: Your conditions do not restrict $R(p,1)$ in any way, they can be arbitrary, and then all others will be uniquely determined. For example, $R(3,2)=2+2R(3,1)$, $R(4,2)=4+4R(3,1)+3R(4,1)$, $R(5,2)=8+8R(3,1)+6R(4,1)+4R(5,1)$, $R(4,3)=11+8R(3,1)+6R(4,1)$, etc.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I am sorry, I wrote R(p,p)=R(1,p)=1 but it really is  R(p,p)=R(p,1)=1 (already edited)and then it works. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand another thing. For which $x$ and $y$ does the recurrence hold? Is $R(x,y)$ with $x<y$ just zero? For example, does it hold for $x=3$, $y=3$, where it gives $R(3,3)=3R(2,3)+R(3,2)$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე by "where for any R(p,c), c does not exceed p" I wanted to say that the function is undefined for R(k,d); where d>k, so it does not hold for R(3,3), because we get an undefined function R(2,3).

Comment: I see. Then your recurrence translates into the following PDE for the generating function $f(u,v)=\sum_{p,c}R(p,c)u^pv^c$:$$u+uv\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}+(u-v)v\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=f(u,v),$$with $f(u,0)=u$. Mathematica gives a general solution in terms of hypergeometric functions, probably it can be simplified.

Comment: Alternatively, one might look at it in the form $f(u,v)=\sum_{c\ge0}g_c(u)v^c$; then, $g_0(u)=u$ while$$g_{c+1}(u)=\frac{ug_c'(u)-cg_c(u)}{1-(c+1)u}$$. Thus $g_1(u)=\frac u{1-u}$, $g_2(u)=\frac{u^2}{(1-u)^2(1-2u)}$, $g_3(u)=\frac{2u^3(2-3u)}{(1-u)^3(1-2u)^2(1-3u)}$, etc.